# Scale beziercurves with a animation

Tags: typescript, canvas, scale

I want to make a animation that scales the 2 Beziercurves of my Heart canvas element. I tried to put a value infront of all beziercurve Values but it just didnt draw the bezier curve anymore. How can i scale both those curve to make it bigger?

Heartdraw()

```
    draw2(): void {

        crc2.beginPath();
        crc2.restore();
        crc2.moveTo(this.x, this.y); 
        crc2.bezierCurveTo(this.x + 82, this.y - 40, this.x, this.y - 80, this.x, this.y - 50);
        crc2.save();
        crc2.stroke();
        crc2.moveTo(this.x, this.y);
        crc2.bezierCurveTo(this.x - 82, this.y - 40, this.x, this.y - 80, this.x, this.y - 50);
        crc2.fillStyle = "Red";
        crc2.fill();
        crc2.restore();
        crc2.closePath();
        crc2.save();


    }

}
```

What i tried befor:

```
    initScale: number = 1;
    scaleVal: number;


    animate(): void {

        if(this.scaleVal == 1){
        this.scaleVal += 2;
        }
        else if (this.scaleVal == 3) {
            this.scaleVal -= 2;
        }

    }




    draw2(): void {

        crc2.beginPath();

        crc2.restore();
        crc2.moveTo(this.x, this.y); 
        crc2.bezierCurveTo(this.scaleVal * this.x + 82, this.scaleVal * this.y - 40, this.scaleVal * this.x, this.scaleVal *  this.y - 80, this.scaleVal * this.x, this.scaleVal *  this.y - 50);
        crc2.save();
        crc2.stroke();
        crc2.moveTo(this.x, this.y);
        crc2.bezierCurveTo(this.x - 82, this.y - 40, this.x, this.y - 80, this.x, this.y - 50);
        crc2.fillStyle = "Red";
        crc2.fill();
        crc2.scale(this.xScale, this.yScale);
        crc2.restore();
        crc2.closePath();
        crc2.save();


    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

### Transforming rendered content

Use the canvas transform to scale rendered content.

The example below uses [ctx.translate](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CanvasRenderingContext2D/translate) to position the render and [`ctx.scale`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CanvasRenderingContext2D/scale) to scale.

The transform is reset with [`ctx.setTransform(1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0)`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CanvasRenderingContext2D/setTransform) which is much quicker than using [`ctx.save`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CanvasRenderingContext2D/save) and [`ctx.restore`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CanvasRenderingContext2D/restore)

### Scale path not stroke

To keep the [`lineWidth`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CanvasRenderingContext2D/lineWidth) constant the transform is reset after the bezier path has been defined and before [`stroke`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CanvasRenderingContext2D/stroke) is called.

```js
requestAnimationFrame(mainLoop);  // start animation
const ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
const heart = {
    x: 100, y : 100, scale : 1,
    draw() {
        ctx.fillStyle = "Red";
        ctx.lineWidth = 4;

        ctx.translate(this.x, this.y);     // set origin 
        ctx.scale(this.scale, this.scale); // set scale

        ctx.beginPath();
        ctx.moveTo(0, 0); 
        ctx.bezierCurveTo(82, -40, 0, -80, 0, -50);
        ctx.bezierCurveTo(0, -80, -80, -40, 0, 0);
        
        // to keep the line width constant reset the transform after defining the path
        ctx.setTransform(1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0);  // restore default transform
        ctx.stroke();
        ctx.fill();
    }
}

function mainLoop(time) {
    ctx.clearRect(0, 0, ctx.canvas.width, ctx.canvas.height);
    heart.scale = Math.sin(time / 100) * 0.2 + 1; // animate scale
    heart.draw();
    requestAnimationFrame(mainLoop);
}
```

```html
<canvas id="canvas"></canvas>
```